# How do I print a bullet character to the console?

Tags: c#, unicode, codepages

This is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("•");
```

Or this:

```
Console.WriteLine("\u2022");
```

The result (on my computer):

> **beep**

The desired result:

```
•
```

How can I make the above character appear on my console?

---

<sub>I understand where the beep comes from, as the bullet is translated into an ASCII `BELL` character. This question came about while trying to understand more about codepage 437.</sub>

Comment: I was thinking ... `Console.WriteLine("•");`

Comment: Per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.outputencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx could set the console to use UTF8, but I haven't tested this.

Comment: @OSborn I tried various encodings (ASCII, Unicode, UTF8, CP437), and none of them worked.

Comment: Wait a minute, somehow the bullet went missing from the original post. I didn't notice until now.

Comment: @Kendall Frey See Rufus's answer: the page I linked has notes about the console font.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to solve the problem much easier than the other options listed. (And it's available now, even if it wasn't when the question was originally asked.)

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: This works fine on Windows 10, but I was running Windows 7 at the time of posting, so it's probably OS-dependent. What OS are you using?

Comment: I think the .NET Framework version is more likely to matter than the version of Windows.

Comment: I tested multiple framework versions and it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

I just remembered a Windows console mode that doesn't process ASCII codes such as the bell and linefeed. I need these functions:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int handle);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr handle, int mode);
```

Before I try writing to the console, I do this:

```
SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(-11), 2);
```

This fetches a handle to the native screen buffer attached to stdout, and disables the ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT flag.

```
Console.WriteLine("•");
```

Output:

```
•♪◙
```

Whoops, that means it won't process the linefeed and carriage return that come from `WriteLine`.

```
Console.Write("•");
```

Output:

```
•
```

Bingo!

Now if I want to revert the console back to 'normal' mode before printing more text, I can do this:

```
SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(-11), 3);
```

Comment: If there is a way of doing this *without* P/Invoke, I would love to hear it.

Comment: This worked for me: `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely have to change your console font to one that supports that character.

Check this article: [Changing Console Fonts](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2009/07/23/changing-console-fonts/)

Comment: I tried changing the font to Consolas (which displays the bullet fine in other programs), but it still beeped at me.

Answer (score 0):

DOS codepages 437 and 850 contains graphical characters for byte values <32. `•` is 7, but 7 is also ASCII BEL control character. .NET, when printing Unicode strings to console, converts them to CP850 or the local equivalent. When you print stuff to console, they get interpreted as Extended ASCII, so byte 7 is interpreted as BEL control character, not the bullet.

If you want to force console to interpret your low byte values as graphical characters, you have to escape them. IMHO .NET should do it automatically, but it doesn't.

[You need to prepend it with `ESC ^`.](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/cp/cp00437.html) So try printing this: `"\x1B^\x07"`

Comment: Interestingly, this doesn't work. It prints `←^` and beeps, so it's obviously treating the bell as a special case, but not the ESC.